# Apache .htaccess rewriting urls, where to start?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I'm new to URL rewriting, but I really need it for a script I'm writing. The problem is, where to start...

I'd like to use .htaccess to rewrite http://mydomain.net/page to http://mydomain.net/view.php?id=page

But, Google is too overflooded with other questions about .htaccess and I can't really find where I am looking for. Do you guys can help me out?

Regards,

Jesse

Comment: Off-topic (questions like this is not good for SO). BTW, you are looking for [this](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html).

Comment: What you're trying to achieve is .htacces 101 and you shoud be able to solve this problem by using Google and one of the first three results.

Comment: How do you mean offtopic?

Comment: @user2001358 Read the FAQ SO is not some kinda look-up community.

Answer (score 1):

This rule would do it:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ view.php?id=$1 [NC]
```

Comment: Just added the rest of the `.htaccess`.

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to accept the answer, so this won't be open for longer than needed.